# Dual-Link DVI-I vs Dual-Link DVI-D to HDMI

Tags: hdmi, dvi

I have an older computer which has two outputs for a monitor: A Dual link DVI-D (24+1) and a Dual link DVI-I (24+5).  I would like to connect this computer to a High Def TV through an HDMI cable to use the TV as a monitor.  What is the advantage of using the DVI-I port instead of the DVI-D port?  Or is there no difference?  I would think that using the port with more connections would be *better* in some way, if I can find the correct cable.  (I seem to be able to find 24+1 cables advertised as DVI-I, but I do not seem to find 24+5 DVI-I cables).  On the other hand, the table found here (https://computermesh.com/types-and-difference-between-dvi-a-dvi-d-dvi-i/) seems to say that there is no difference between DVI-D and DVI-I as long as they are both dual link (ignoring analog compatibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDMI is digital only.
The analog part of the DVI output won't be used at all in a DVI-HDMI converter plug/cable.
So it should not make any difference.

Furthermore the analog part of DVI-I isn't dual-link. It is single link.
Only the digital part can have the dual-link functionality.
That's probably why you can't find such a cable.